# How to create a DataSelectField with a list of all the blocks of the current page Pirnaha CMS

Tags: piranha-cms

I'm am trying to make a TabView for the user. The idea that I came up with is in the manager to create a GroupBlock that holds all the buttons ("tabs") of the TabView and I want to give each of them a DataSelectField where the manager can select what block the tab should contain. I looked over the PageItem example ([page item](https://piranhacms.org/docs/master/content/fields)), but I don't know how to get all the blocks of the current page. Any ideas with this? Or how a TabView should be created?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, I found a work-around. I did not use a DataSelectField. What I did is to create a TabBlock (Block) that has a dictionary with string keys and a list of BaseTabBlockGroup. This BaseTabBlockGroupis a BlockGroup that contains a StringField that is the name of the Tab. In the page model, I created a service that searches through all the Blocks in the page and for each BaseTabBlockGroupit either makes a new entry in the dictionary or it appends the blockGroup to the existing list. It is important to also eliminate the BaseTabBlockGroup element from the list of blocks of the page, so that they appear only in the TabView.

To display the TabView I used Bootstrap 5 ([navs and tabs bs5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior)). I won't provide a implementation for this since I think this is pretty easy to do.

Thank you!